# beamer, verbatim, and `\end{frame}`

Tags: beamer, verbatim

as of current TL2018 a minimal beamer/verbatim file containing a line `\end{frame}` in the verbatim code fails to compile:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{verbatim}
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{My first slide}
Hello World
\end{frame}
\end{document}
\end{verbatim}
  Hello
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If I comment the `\end{frame}` line in the verbatim block all is fine.

The error is

```
Runaway argument?
^^M\documentclass{beamer}^^M\begin{document}^^M\begin{frame}{My first\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.10 \end{frame}
```

Comment: Yes ... and? Do you want a work-round (basically using the ability to call the 'real' slide environment something else).

Comment: It's really hackish, but you could trick beamer into ignoring the first `\end{frame}` by adding something after it, like an ASCII tab, which wouldn't show in the output.

Comment: Note I've had various issues in this area as the common case of e.g. allowing indented frames in general can conflict with convenience for `beamer` demos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nesting frames for documenting `beamer` itself is of course a somewhat special case. Here, you can use the ability to create an 'alternative name' environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newenvironment{slide}{\begin{frame}[fragile,environment=slide]}{\end{frame}}
\begin{document}
\begin{slide}
\begin{verbatim}
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{My first slide}
Hello World
\end{frame}
\end{document}
\end{verbatim}
  Hello
\end{slide}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this indeed works. *But* the above code was working at least about a year ago - I was reusing a presentation I had and suddenly it stopped compiling. So it is a regression ;-) Anyway, thanks for the quick fix.

Comment: @norbert Not a regression, rather a change where I had to make a choice. Allowing indented frames in general meant breaking the very special case of `beamer` slides about `beamer` slides.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but what do you mean with "indented frames"? Does it mean that the final `\end{verbatim}` now can be indented arbitrarily and doors not need to start at the first column?